# Angular-ui-bootstrap modal not showing data passed to it

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to pass some model data into a modal window when it opens. Its in a $http.post success and also in failure `then()` with some different titles and button texts. I pass multiple data to it like:

```
//.then(){...//same as below }
,function (response){
     $scope.PostRespData = response.data.message || 'Rq Failed';

     $scope.pn = $scope.PostRespData.substring(53,63);

     //(status=400) response modal string
     $scope.name = 'Hey there!';

     //modal options
     $scope.opts = {
                backdrop: true,
                backdropClick: true,
                dialogFade: false,
                keyboard: true,
                templateUrl : 'alreadyexists.html',
                controller : ModalInstanceCtrl,
                resolve: {}
                };


    $scope.opts.resolve.item = function() {
                   return angular.copy({name:$scope.name, errmsg:$scope.PostRespData, num:$scope.pn}); // pass name to modal dialo
                        }

     //open the modal and create a modal Isntance
     var modalInstance = $uibModal.open($scope.opts);

     var ModalInstanceCtrl = function($scope, $uibModalInstance, $uibModal, item) {

          $scope.item = item;

          $scope.ok = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close();

          };

          $scope.cancel = function () {
          $uibModalInstance.close();
                        }
```

My HTML template looks like

```
<div class="modal-header">
  <h1>{{item.name}}</h1>
</div>
<div ng-controller="Nav" class="modal-body">
<p>{{item.errmsg}}
    <a href="http://myserver.com/page.jsp?num="+{{item.num}}+"&c=y">View {{item.num}}</a>
</p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">Edit Current Details</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Edit {{item.num}}</button>
</div>
```

I get my modal and I also get the static data but data being passed to it does not reflect. I've spent the whole day trying to make this work.

Edit: Adding current output pic.[image: Data not being passed to modal]

Please help me!

Comment: won't solve your problem but suggest not assigning things to `$scope` that aren't needed in view. `$scope.opts` could simply be `var modalOpts` . Create a simple demo that reproduces the problem. Not easy to see why it doesn't work right now

Comment: Even I don't understand why it does not work. I've tried so much but failed. I do not get an error in the Chrome debugger but I think the data is not being passed to the modal instance. I have tried to add it directly in `resolve` but that did not change anything.

Comment: the injection of `item` must be working which means something is being resolved. What do you get in console inside modal controller when you log item?

Comment: doesn't the modal instance controller need to be an angular controller?
When i look at the example, it is really different
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal

Comment: @charlietfl it never goes inside the `var ModalInstanceCtrl = fn..`. That's why I was saying the data is not being passed to the instance. I did not use a console.log(item) there before but now it does not return anything since it never enters that module.

Comment: @TobiasTimm it can be  function

Comment: need to create a demo that reproduces this. can use `$http` in plunker

Comment: @charlietfl ah okay, quite a long time since i've worked with angular-ui ^^

Comment: Yes I was just going to make a plunker but I managed to solve it. So, the `var ModalInstance = fn..` needs to be outside the `$http` much like an independent function. Although, I'm trying to run my head around it still as to why that is the case.

Comment: @TobiasTimm here is a sample [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LuotDnQX1RuMKSTWy3zd?p=preview) It can be a function. Here, if you push in the `var ModalInstance = fn..` inside the button call, you'll see it wouldn't work. I can't really answer why though!

Comment: @charlietfl any idea why that is the case?

Comment: I know now what it is ...it's a javascript **hoisting** problem. if you changed the function declaration to `function ModalInstanceCtrl(..){}` it would hoist properly. Since you used `var xxx = func` and put it below only the undefined variable gets hoisted

Comment: @charlietfl thanks for some clarification. So you mean if I declare `var xxx` earlier in the code, it would not be a problem here?

Comment: only if you assign the function earlier before passing to options object. A proper function declaration works differently and would get hoisted properly. Read up on how `hoisting` works

Comment: I just did and understood the problem. Thanks for the clarification! Good lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by @charlietfl, it was a hoisting issue. To use the above code, move `var ModalInstanceCtrl = func..` outside the button's `ng-click` call of `$http`.